# OData paging with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've managed to implement `$inlinecount` with WebApi.OData (v 4.0.0) using the `ODataQueryOptions<T>` and `PageResult<T>` classes like this:

POCO

```
public class Poco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[ActionName("Default")]
public PageResult<Poco> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Poco> queryOptions)
{
    var data = new Poco[] { 
        new Poco() { id = 1, name = "one", type = "a" },
        new Poco() { id = 2, name = "two", type = "b" },
        new Poco() { id = 3, name = "three", type = "c" },
        new Poco() { id = 4, name = "four", type = "d" },
        new Poco() { id = 5, name = "five", type = "e" },
        new Poco() { id = 6, name = "six", type = "f" },
        new Poco() { id = 7, name = "seven", type = "g" },
        new Poco() { id = 8, name = "eight", type = "h" },
        new Poco() { id = 9, name = "nine", type = "i" }
    };

    var t = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxTop = 2 };
    queryOptions.Validate(t);
    var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 1 };
    IQueryable results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(data.AsQueryable(), s);

    var next = Request.GetNextPageLink();
    var count = Request.GetInlineCount();

    return new System.Web.Http.OData.PageResult<Poco>(
        results as IEnumerable<Poco>, next, count);
}
```

I'm getting error 406 when I switch from JSON to old school XmlSerializer. Does anyone know if this should work?

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageResult` can't be serialized by `XmlSerializer` because it doesn't have a public, parameterless constructor. But there's nothing stopping you from defining your own similar type that does have a public, parameterless constructor. It should be pretty simple to do. I'd recommend taking a look at the source code for `PageResult` and adopting a similar approach.